# Arduino Scripting issue

Tags: c++, arduino, ide

I'm currently trying to make a RC car on Arduino and facing the following issue, where I'm unable to reset the L298P Motor Driver (By Keyes) Shield to stop motor from moving (Using only one motor at Motor B port).

Basically, the motor sticks to one direction rotating and not stopping when JoyStick's position is resetted.

Here's the current code I'm using. (Also Includes my pathetic trials).

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8);

int JoyStick_X = 0; //Analog
int JoyStick_Y = 1; //Analog
int JoyStick_Z = 1; //Digital

int SpeedPin = 11;
int Direction = 13;

void setup(void) {
  myservo.attach(9);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();

  pinMode(JoyStick_Z, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(Direction, OUTPUT);


  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  int x, y, z;
  x = analogRead(JoyStick_X);
  y = analogRead(JoyStick_Y);
  z = digitalRead(JoyStick_Z);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Car Status");

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Spd:");
  lcd.print(x);
  /* if (z == 0) {
     lcd.print("High");
    }
    else if (z == 0 && x < 250) {
     lcd.print("RHgh");
    }
    else if (x > 510 && x < 530) {
     lcd.print("No  ");
    }
    else if (x > 530 && x < 730) {
     lcd.print("Low ");
    }
    else if (x > 730) {
     lcd.print("Med ");
    }
    else if (x < 510 && x > 250) {
     lcd.print("RLow");
    }
    else if (x < 250) {
     lcd.print("RMed");
    }*/

  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.setCursor(10, 1);
  lcd.print("Trn:");

  if (y < 500) {
    lcd.print("L ");
  }
  else if (525 > y && y > 500) {
    lcd.print("-");
  }
  else if (y > 525) {
    lcd.print("R ");
  }

  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print("Bst:");
  if (z == 0) {
    lcd.print("Y");
  }
  else {
    lcd.print("N");
  }

  myservo.write(40 + y * 8.7890625 / 100);

    if (x > 530) {
      digitalWrite(Direction, HIGH);
    }
    else if (x < 510) {
      digitalWrite(Direction, LOW);
    }
    if (x > 510 && x < 530) {
      digitalWrite(0, 0);
    }


  //int speed = ((0.520408 * x ) - 275.816326 );

  analogWrite(SpeedPin, 255);

  /*int value = 255;
    digitalWrite(M1,LOW);

    analogWrite(E1, value);*/


/*var n;
  switch (n)
  {
    case 1:
      digitalWrite(Direction, HIGH);
      break;
    case 2:
      digitalWrite(Direction, LOW);
      break;
    default:
      digitalWrite(0, 0);
  }*/
}
```

Comment: And where are you trying to stop the motor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing `analogWrite(SpeedPin, 0);` somewhere in your code.  Since `SpeedPin` seems to be how you're controlling speed, you need to write  a zero to it to stop.